# Standard SMT button size?

Tags: surface-mount, button

I need an SMT pushbutton on my PCB. I'm drowning in options on Mouser and just want to select something that is future-proof. Is there a standard size and footprint for pushbuttons that I can use to avoid shooting myself in the foot?

Comment: No, but many tactile sensors have 4 pads with the same pints and similar sizes.

Comment: Trust me, a tact switch is not something you need to worry about becoming out of stock.

Comment: You have the standard but slitly bigger BF3000.

Comment: Simply order your search results by the in-stock quantity. You can't go wrong with devices stocked in tens or hundreds of thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, sort by what's in stock. That's usually a good indication of what lots of others are using.

Also, you may want to check out the [Common Parts Library](https://octopart.com/common-parts-library). A group of organizations got together to pick out specific parts of common components. I haven't personally ordered anything based on the list, but they do look like very common parts. Who knows how long it will last or if it will ever take off, but there appears to be a decent amount of people involved. It also looks geared toward the hobbyist. Looks like a good place to start anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is very typical button:

[image]

Name: *Pushbutton Switches SPST OFF(ON) RND SMT MINI PB TACT SWITCH*

It has very typical footprint available in many (if not all) programs for PCB design.

You can always look at stocks on Mouser or other supplier website to avoid buying "not typical" or "weird" product that may be not available later. Currently they have are over 10000pcs in stock.